# AutoHotKey variable assigning in hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make an AutoHotkey hotstring and I couldn't find anything, despite scouring the web.
I'm not quite sure how to explain, but here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
`::sendback {thingtosendback}::{thingtosendback}`
would (theoretically) send back the input, so `sendback wow` would just write `wow`, `sendback hi` would just write `hi` etc. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to combine a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) with the [`Input`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) command.

Simple example:

```
:X:sendback::
    Input, output, T3, {Enter}
    SendInput, % output
return
```

`X` [option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) in the hotstring to execute instead of replace text.
`T3` [option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm#Parameters) in the `Input` command to specify a 3 second timeout for it.
`{Enter}` to mark the end key for the `Input` command.
Then a check if we timed out or not, if not, we [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) whatever we typed.

There's a lot of customization you can on both the hotstring and `Input` command side of things.
Read the documentation to see the possibilities.